# M/GI/1 service time distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, queueing-theory

I want to compute the distribution of the **waiting time** and the number of jobs for M/GI/1 where the service time is Heavy-Tailed or more specifically Pareto. I found this paper http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1340307. However, I cannot understand at the end of the day how I can compute these distributions. Can someone explain it to me simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Pollaczek–Khinchine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollaczek%E2%80%93Khinchine_formula) to compute the transform of the response time W as
$$W^\ast(s) = \frac{(1-\rho)s g(s)}{s-\lambda(1-g(s))}$$ 
(where g(s) is the transform of service time pdf). See Diagle's book for more details

- Daigle, N. *[The Basic M/G/1 Queueing System.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/0-387-22859-4_5)* Queueing Theory with Applications to Packet Telecommunication (2005): 159-223 (pages [165-66 available on Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EkSsgr-d8ZoC&lpg=PR20&ots=-wF7stYd7x&pg=PA165)).

These may also be of interest, in particular the explicit results for your case (heavy tailed distributions).

- Takacs, L. *[Delay distributions for one line with Poisson input, general holding times, and various orders of service.](ftp://helpedia.com/pub/archive/temp/Bell/bstj/vol42-1963/articles/bstj42-2-487.pdf)* Bell System Technical Journal 42 (1963): 487-504.
- Abate, Joseph, and Ward Whitt. *[Explicit M/G/1 waiting-time distributions for a class of long-tail service-time distributions.](http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/ExplicitORletters99.pdf)* Operations Research Letters 25.1 (1999): 25-31.

Answer (score 0):

Is it M/G/1 or M/GI/1? Moreover, are you asking about just the time spent receiving service or total delay (service+wait time).

If it is just service time, then isn't it given by G?!

Comment: OK I fixed that it is M/GI/1 and I want waiting time. Even total delay (sojourn time) is good for me but I'm not sure if it is easier or not.

Comment: Hello Mahdi, welcome to math.stackexchange! As what you have posted is not really answer, but rather a request of clarification, it is better to post it as a comment and not as an answer.